# How to append elements in head tag from iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

1 ) I want to dynamically create an iframe.

**2 )** I have mocked data ( string templates ) for head and body tags.

3 ) I want to create the iframe with the given data from **2 )**

**Code**

```
  var bodyHtml = '<p>Content</p>';
  var headHtml = '<title>Title</title>';

  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

  // inject the bodyHTML to locally iframe
  iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(bodyHtml );

  // headHtml how ?

  // inject my iframe in the DOM
  $('mySelector').append(iframe);
```

How do I inject the **headHtml** in the iframe head tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already done most of the work. The content of the document isn't just the body, it's the whole thing, so you build up the whole thing and then pass that to `encodeURIComponent` (rather than `encodeURI`):

```js
var bodyHtml = '<p>Content</p>';
var headHtml = '<title>Title</title>';

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

// inject the bodyHTML to locally iframe
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(
  "<!doctype html>" +
  "<html>" +
  "<head>" + headHtml + "</head>" +
  "<body>" + bodyHtml + "</body>" +
  "</html>"
);

// inject my iframe in the DOM
$('body').append(iframe);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or with ES2015+ syntax (in particular, a template literal):

```
// inject the bodyHTML to locally iframe
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(`
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>${headHtml}</head>
  <body>${bodyHtml}</body>
  </html>
`);
```

Live Example:

```js
const bodyHtml = '<p>Content</p>';
const headHtml = '<title>Title</title>';

const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

// inject the bodyHTML to locally iframe
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(`
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>${headHtml}</head>
  <body>${bodyHtml}</body>
  </html>
`);

// inject my iframe in the DOM
$('body').append(iframe);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```